# Maple bug? How to calculate the asymptotic expansion of the generalised harmonic function?

Tags: asymptotics, harmonic-numbers, maple

If I run the following command in Maple

```
asympt(harmonic(n, 1/2), n, 1)
```

the output is
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}+\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\right).$$
Is this a bug? Why is the answer negative? My understanding is that `harmonic(n,1/2)` calculates the following sum
$$H_n^{(1/2)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^{1/2}},$$
so why does Maple give a negative expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of the harmonic function of two arguments, it's defined as harmonic(a,z)=$\zeta(z)-\zeta(0,z,a+1)$. For $\mathrm{Re}(z)>1$, $\zeta(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^z}$ and $\zeta(n,z,v)=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial z^n} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+v)^z}$.

Thus for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>1$ harmonic(n,z)=$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^z} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+n+1)^z}$.

"Formal simplification" of this expression for positive integer $n$ appears to result in $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^z}$ which is what you actually want to get. But "formal simplification" is not how this function is defined for $\mathrm{Re}(z) \leq 1$. It is instead defined by analytic continuation of the two zeta functions separately.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to the asymptotic series of $H_n^{(1/2)}$ using Maple?

Comment: @Peanutlex I don't really know Maple well, but you should be able to set up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula semi-manually without much difficulty.

Comment: @Peanutlex For instance the beginning of it is $2n^{1/2}-2+\frac{1+n^{-1/2}}{2}$. The difficulty in this approach is that all the terms being evaluated at $1$ don't scale with $n$, so strictly speaking you have to sum all of those up to just get the leading order term. And it's not obvious to me that $\sum \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} \left. \frac{d^{2k-1}}{dx^{2k-1}} x^{-1/2} \right |_{x=1}$ is summable at all.

Comment: @Peanutlex However Mathematica seems to be telling me that you actually want to be looking at $H_{1/n}^{(1/2)}$ in the sense I said in the answer, and it gives the series easily. It gives the first two terms as $2\sqrt{n}+\zeta(1/2)$. Try putting "series for sum from k=1 to n of k^(-1/2) at n=infinity" into Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Thank you very much that works. I think we can conclude that this is a bug in Maple.

Comment: @Peanutlex It's not a bug. It's a function defined in a way that is more or less natural to professional mathematicians and less natural to others. The documentation makes the definition clear. There is probably a way to ask Maple an analogue of what I said instead of trying to use "harmonic" as a shorthand.

Comment: I used `asympt(sum(k^(-1/2),k=1..n),n,1)` to get what I wanted in Maple.

Answer (score 1):

For the most general case $$H_n^{(p)}=n^{-p} \left(-\frac{n}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{p}{12 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)+\zeta (p)$$ So, if $p=\frac 12$
$$H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{{n}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)=2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\right) $$